# Where to put piece of code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, screen-scraping

I found a script which makes it possible to screen scrape a website, example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4QCt/97/)

The problem is that I want to include another script from "Embed.ly" This script allows to "enrich" a given link. The code for this is very simple:

```
  $('div.content').embedly({key: 41f042ec20b04dda84448dc4a46d357d});
```

However I can't seem to give it an appropriate place within the script. It doesn't work wherever I put it, but even worse the screen scraping script also stops working. So where in the script should I put my embedly code??

Comment: ps the url mashable.com doesn't seem to react very fast, you can try some other link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's mainly the cross origin script...

http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/m4QCt/103/

I commented out the find links part because the response of the `jquery.xdomainajax.js`lib is returning jibbrish... (It seems to work half of the time!?)

Minor details: you're api key needs quotes around it, the url needs to be in the href part to make the embedly work, you need to select '.content' to append the links to and you don't need the `$('.content')` just the selector is fine as parameter for append. (both will work ;) )

You can write your own proxy script for dealing with the cross origin issues... A proxy script is a sort of middleware. You make a request to the script the script gets the data, and returns it to you. For example [php proxy](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.de/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html). You can make the same thing in asp, jsp, flash or even java applet.

**EDIT:**

response I was getting half of the time...

[image: Jibbrish]

Comment: I don't think it returns jibbrish...There valid links, there just squished together, so it looks like jibbrish...Furthermore there is nothing wrong with embedly code (been working with it long time and I know it processes every url)

Comment: sorry typo in the key ;) and it's only half of the time returning jibbrish :p

Comment: I updated the fiddle link and it seems to work for now ;) I just don't really trust the xdomainajax lib.. It can be a cause of the slow performance too..

Comment: Thank you very much:) (as for now I dont really have an option regarding screen scraping, so I have to use this one)